# Populating a large custom table with many results from methods. Is there a better way?

Tags: apex, visualforce

- I have a custom sortable Visualforce table that is 13 columns by 20
  rows large.
- Every cell needs to be populated with aggregated data from the Opportunity object.
- I am currently doing this via methods in a custom controller.
- This means I will end up with a custom controller which has a huge number of methods.

Here is one method. The other methods I have are the same except the recordtypeid will change and the month will increment up to 12 (December).

```
public Double getJanuary() {
    //AggregateResult[] closedOpportunityStats = [SELECT SUM(Amount)amt FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId = '012D00000003HW4' AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Billing_Effective_Date__c) = 1 AND IsClosed = TRUE];
    Double amountX = (Double)[SELECT SUM(Amount)amt FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId = '012D00000003HW4' AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Billing_Effective_Date__c) = 1 AND IsClosed = TRUE][0].get('amt');
    return amountX;
}
```

I am placing the setter in the Visualforce table, like so:

```
<td class="tg-6k2t"><b><u>New Business</u> - closed won</b></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"><apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###, ### .##}"><apex:param value="{!January}"/></apex:outputText></td>                                                                
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t"></td>
  </tr>
```

So all that work has been done just to populate the amount of a certain type of Opportunity for January. I then need to do the same for Feb, March, April, May etc etc.

**Is there any better way to achieve this?** I was thinking I could write a trigger onto the opportunity object or a custom object which would house the monthly SUM(AMOUNT) opportunity figures. But I figure that since this Visualforce page would be accessed only on a periodic basis, then this would be less overhead.

Comment: Well, definitely remove hard-coded ids...

Comment: :) yes, of course

Comment: Why not run a batch class that you schedule to run on the 1st of each month that populates a custom object with the data for each field in the table? Have it create a new record who's name is the Month + Year! You could make it a child of Opportunity if you wanted to, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev - I had thought to do this but the requirement is to have it in real time. Therefore, if if an opportunity has just been closed won, for example, it should appear in the table when it is next accessed.

Comment: Gotcha. That part wasn't clear. I'd still think about kicking off an asynchronous update using the same approach via an AfterUpdate trigger that fires a batch class to do this for you and write it to a custom object. Your page will load a lot faster if you do.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a rule of thumb for how long a single method returning a result from a soql will take to load in a page, at all?